# Eclipse Product Export error

Tags: export, eclipse-rcp

Hi I have an Eclipse RCP application. I have a plugin and an associated feature. In order to create an executable file for the RCP application, I am running Eclipse product export wizard. When I run the wizard I am getting the following error:

Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.e4.rcp: Unable to find plug-in: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.13.0.v20150603-0857. Please check the error log for more details.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Well the build can't find the`org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.13.0.v20150603-0857` plugin jar (that exact version of the jar). Possibly you are using a `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature from a different version of Eclipse to the version you are using for the plugins.

Comment: When I run 'Launch an Eclipse application' link in the product configuration the app runs fine. But when I export with the wizard it fails with the message. Initially the app was developed from the previous version of Eclipse. Then I have upgraded Eclipse to Mars. Could this be the cause? It was working before. If so, without going back to the previous Eclipse, can I resolve the issue? I have downloaded the missing jar and put it in plugin directory. But it doesn't show.

Comment: You can't just download random jars. Everything you use must come from a single Eclipse release.

Comment: Set up a [target platform](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) and make sure all the Eclipse plugins and features come from that.